# Media query not being seen? Css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am having an issue where I decided that at the bottom of the `style.css` I would do all my styles above

```
.searchMoveDown, .moveIcons{
    display:visible;
}

@media (max-width: 768){
   /* Hide the search and icons in the nav.*/
  .searchMoveDown, .moveIcons{
      display:none;
  }
}
```

When I shrink down the screen to less then 768px, the two classes are still visible when clearly I said `display: none;` whats worse is that chrome is not seeing the media queries. Now I decided to do it in one style sheet mainly because that's how bootstrap is doing it, and it seems more cleaner then fetching two style sheets.

Am I missing something or ....

Too me these do not work and maybe I am just crazy.

Comment: Have you tried validating your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing px in your media query .

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
       /* Hide the search and icons in the nav.*/
      .searchMoveDown, .moveIcons{
          display:none;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I knew it was something stupid >.>

Comment: lol we all do it @LogicLooking

Comment: A CSS validator is a good first defence against such mental lapses.

Comment: @Diodeus "Invalid property fill", "Sorry, the at-rule @-webkit-keyframes is unknown"… kill me now.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the unit in the query!

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
   /* Hide the search and icons in the nav.*/
  .searchMoveDown, .moveIcons{
      display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, Donte' Trumble beat me to it! :-)

Comment: hahaha lol I want those points lol